# Pandas: converting amount of seconds into timedeltas or times

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have an amount of seconds in a dataframe, let's say:

```
s = 122
```

I want to convert it to the following format:

```
00:02:02.0000
```

To do that I try using to_datetime the following way:

```
 pd.to_datetime(s, format='%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

However this doesn't work:

> ValueError: time data 122 does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f' (match)

I also tried using `unit='ms'` instead of format, but then I get the date before the time.
How can I modify my code to get the desired convertion ?

It needs to be done in the dataframe using pandas if possible.

EDIT: both jezrael and MedAli solutions below are valid, however Jezrael solution have the advantage to work not only with integers but also with Datetime.time as input!

Comment: I sugegst use `timedelta`  - `datetime.timedelta(seconds=s)`

Comment: This is not a duplicate since I am trying to achieve that using Pandas functions, not string to date from the standard library.
Thanks, but will that work on the whole dataframe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with convert seconds to `nanoseconds`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sec':[122,3,5,7,1,0]})

df['t'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['sec'] * 10**9)

print (df)
   sec        t
0  122 00:02:02
1    3 00:00:03
2    5 00:00:05
3    7 00:00:07
4    1 00:00:01
5    0 00:00:00
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly the function I was missing! thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, advantage between `timedelta`s and `time`s is pandas native support [timedeltas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your code as follows to get the desired result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sec':[122,3,5,7,1,0]})
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.sec, unit="s").dt.time
```

Output:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
   sec      time
0  110  00:01:50
1    3  00:00:03
2    5  00:00:05
3    7  00:00:07
4    1  00:00:01
5    0  00:00:00
```